# Forcing maven assembly plugin to run after maven profile changed properties

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-profiles

I'm using maven assembly plugin with profiles to generate a zip file with the structure of the application and to guarantee that the paths are correct:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>desenvolvimento</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <arquivo_tef4j>classpath:tef4j.properties</arquivo_tef4j>
            <arquivo_bd>classpath:bancoDados.properties</arquivo_bd>
            <arquivo_aplicacao>classpath:aplicacao.properties</arquivo_aplicacao>
            <modelo_dav>classpath:modelos_relatorio/dav.rptdesign</modelo_dav>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>producao</id>
        <properties>
            <arquivo_tef4j>file:../config/tef4j.properties</arquivo_tef4j>
            <arquivo_bd>file:../config/bancoDados.properties</arquivo_bd>
            <arquivo_aplicacao>file:../config/aplicacao.properties</arquivo_aplicacao>
            <modelo_dav>file:../modelos/dav.rptdesign</modelo_dav>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                <mainClass>com.hrgi.pdv.App</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.hrgi.pdv.App</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The profile named "desenvolvimento" is used in development with the IDE, the other profile is used to generate the production's zip file. As you can see, the differences in profiles are basically in properties values. They are working well when I'm using "desenvolvimento" profile, but I'm having some problem with the property "modelo_dav" in the second profile.
This property is used in "aplicacao.properties", but the assembly plugin copies the "aplicacao.properties" without changing property ${modelo_dav}, if I open the jar file the "aplicacao.properties" file has the correct value, so I'm assuming that the assembly plugin is copying the file before maven change the properties.
Is there a way I can force assembly plugin to copy the file after maven changed the properties? Another question is: how can I remove properties file from final jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly runs on the `package` phase, which is the same as the jar, and is after the `process-resources` phase, which is the one that is handling the filtering, at least by default.  So, this suggests it's not a sequencing issue.

I would suggest that you closely examine, and do some sort of testing, to determine exactly where the assembly is picking up the file from.  It could be grabbing the one directly from the unprocessed source side, rather than target.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to make assembly plugin copy resource files from build directory rather than source directory, as follows:
change

```html
<fileSet>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*.properties</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

into

```html
<fileSet>
  <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
  <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*.properties</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```